# Pivot SelectedItem property is causing crash in Windows UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

As shown in the below code i have used a pivot control to display data and in the selection changed of pivot control i have called a method so that it will select the header value dynamically and displays the data.

XAML Code:

```
<Pivot x:Name="pivot" SelectionChanged="BindData">
      <PivotItem Header="Test1"></PivotItem>
      <PivotItem Header="Test2"></PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

C# Code:

```
private async void BindData(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     dynamic selectedValue = pivot.SelectedItem;
     if (selectedValue != null)
    {
                    PropertyInfo pi = selectedValue.GetType().GetProperty("Header");
                    string sectionName = (String)(pi.GetValue(selectedValue, null));
    }
}
```

The code is working seamlessly fine in the Debug mode, but causing a crash in the release mode.
What might be the issue for this? Any workaround? or any settings i am missing?
Kindly help me on this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using reflection when you don't need to?

The `PivotItem` class exposes the `Header` property, so you can just use:

```
private void BindData(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = pivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem;    // Gets the selected item and casts it from an object to a PivotItem.
    var sectionName = selectedItem?.Header as string;      // "selectedItem?" - makes sure selectedItem isn't null. ".Header as string" - gets the Header property and casts it from an object to  a string.
}
```

That should work just fine in Release mode.